# Precompiling uploaded assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, assets, precompiled

I have a rails 3.1 application where users upload pictures. I am storing them in /assets/images since that is the path image_tag looks for instead of public/images.

Everything works fine in development but I deployed to Heroku and it gives me this error:

> ActionView::Template::Error (image_name.jpeg isn't precompiled)

What is the right way to handle such a situation? Is there a way to compile images after uploading or should I store them somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You **must not** use the filesystem on Heroku to store uploads.
- You should not use `image_path` with uploaded images, since that assumes it is looking at the filesystem. If you use `image_tag`, you must pass a complete URL, not just an image name.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using carrierwave for your images uploads? You can store them on amazon S3 reasonably easy with carrier wave. [Carrierwave instructions](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) Other solutions have S3 storage easily accessible as well.

Heroku will NOT let you store files in the filesystem. Run

`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

to compile you assets locally, add to git, and push to heroku but you cannot add images later via your application on heroku. If you upload them to the `/temp` folder they will stay there for a short while or until you re-deploy/update your code I believe.