# Heroku error "Unexpected error while processing request: can't convert nil into String"

Tags: heroku, sinatra

I have a Sinatra app that is located here https://github.com/trivektor/Backbone-Hangman. The first time I push it to Heroku, everything worked fine. However, on the second push my application crashed. The only thing that I changed was CSS. Checking the logs, I found the message

Unexpected error while processing request: can't convert nil into String

Does anyone know why this is happening? Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a full stacktrace? Does it give a line number?

Answer (score 1):

Sometime the lack of a closing `}` can cause this. Check those in all your css files and prescompile assets for production. 
`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`Here is some more [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663179/precompiling-uploaded-assets/8665067#8665067)

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error in a Sinatra app this week.  Looking at the git repo provided by this questions author, I saw [this commit](https://github.com/trivektor/Backbone-Hangman/commit/a568cde0aad962802be2dc745fbb9845145a6fc3). It fixed the issue I was having.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue using `sinatra-activerecord`. Updating my database and rebooting the environment did the trick for me:

`rake db:migrate`